# Introducing [gap] tag as a synonym for [gap-system] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/) is an open source mathematical software system. It provides a [programming language, also called GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap4.html).

On Stack Exchange, questions about GAP can be found at:

- Mathematics, under the `gap` tag: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gap
- MathOverflow, under the `gap` tag: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/gap
- Stack Overflow, under the [gap-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gap-system) tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gap-system

I have observed that many GAP questions on Stack Overflow were not assigned the [gap-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gap-system) tag, and hence remained unnoticed for a long time. Would it be useful to introduce a synonym [gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gap) for the [gap-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gap-system) tag? Having the same tag name for all three Q&A sites will be less confusing, and may also help when a question needs to be migrated from one site to another.

At the moment, trying to find a tag for GAP shows the 6 most popular tags including the substring `gap`, ignoring hyphens (see the image below), so it shows e.g. `bing-api`, but not `gap`, so unsurprisingly the [gap-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gap-system) tag  has little visibility.

[image: trying-to-find-gap-tag]

Comment: A [gap] tag would quickly be overrun by questions about gaps between visual elements in UIs, gaps in lists and arrays and how to work around them, etc.. Maybe adding a [gap] tag and immediately adding as a synonym to [gap-system] would work, but considering how many people mis-tag [asp.net-mvc] questions as [asp.net] [model-view-controller], expect to spend a lot of time retagging questions marked [html] [css] [gap-system] and the like...

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey - that could happen, but with currently 54 questions in [gaps-in-data] and 58 in [gaps-in-visuals], that may be manageable. At least in this case I will get notifications about new questions under the [gap] tag, and will be able to retag them, while otherwise questions about GAP asked here are hard to discover by other GAP users and developers.

Comment: P.S. @HereticMonkey one could also use the extended tag description to direct users to other similarly-named tags, like e.g. SageMath does in the [[sage](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sage/info)] tag.

Comment: Yeah, it's been my experience that few people read the tag descriptions... Or to be more precise, the people who often make tagging errors don't read the tag descriptions. For instance, the [web] tag's excerpt begins with "Do not use this tag" yet I end up editing it out of at least five questions a day. I'm sure there are others who are much more diligent than I. YMMV, and I think you're right that you've got a small workload so it could be that the reward outweighs the risk. I just wanted to warn you of my experience, so you don't become a burnt-out curmudgeon like me :).

Comment: For the record, just happened that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63363913/) was wrongly assigned the [gap-system] tag.

Comment: @OlexandrKonovalov This also holds for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71447450/how-can-i-change-the-gap-of-only-element, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71275111/how-can-i-set-the-gap-limit-in-cplex and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68086572/how-to-use-gap-in-vscode.

Comment: @StefanKohl edited the 1st one, thanks, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68086572/how-to-use-gap-in-vscode is a genuine question about GAP

Comment: @OlexandrKonovalov Ah o.k. -- before clicking on the screenshot link, to me it seemed to be about one of the other GAP's ... .